# epicor baq search not working

Tags: erp, epicorerp

I have created a BAQ in epicor 905700c. Under the BAQ Search tab I have selected Part.PartNum as the "Like" column. But when I try to use this BAQ for a part search it doesn't work properly.

For instance, if I open Part Maintenance, and click the part button to search for available parts, the search form pops up. I select the BAQ search I just created. The search actually returns results, but when I try to select one, it does not populate the part field.

This happens for every BAQ I have hooked up by way of partnum. All other BAQ searches work.

I assume there is a setting somewhere in Epicor that did not get turned on properly when we did the install. Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create a BAQ for the part table in a couple of clients databases that are on the same version, Epicor 9.05700.  It did not work on any of them.  After a call with Epicor, they know that it is a bug.  Not sure if the patch is ready yet, but if you are on maintenance you can call and see about getting it.